# Visitor's reactions on web development agency's page?

Tags: website-design, layout, branding

I need to step-up of the freelance side and step into a more business side of web agencies and I need your opinions about how people react on your philosophy and decide to go or leave you.

The way I like to present my web company page, is not the "standard" one. Basically I refer to the layout and therefore the philosophy of the page you represent.

I have posted one sample below, clean and simple, minimal, less is more.

Of course, portfolio will include various of pages, minimal, colorful themes.. you know.

My question is how a minimal, simple, clean site affect visitor's - and probably future client's - behavior and choice.

Are there any researches that showed whether visitors who looks for an agency to build their "disneyland like page" will leave your page as soon as they see your simplicity? And on the other hand, did a research showed that you attract more serious projects?

Thank you for all of your info

[image]

Comment: Are branding and marketing issues on topic?

Comment: Well kinda yes. We all need customers.

Comment: Well kinda yes. We all need customers and a strong name.

Comment: Branding is a big part of UX. Comfortable brands make users comfortable, a lack of branding can make a site feel cheap or confusing--"who the heck's site is this anyway?"

Comment: Do you really want clients who expect 'disneyland' web sites?

Comment: @DA01 Where I live, people live in ie6 ...

Comment: @Nikolai IE6 is less Disney Land and more McDonald's play land off the I-95 exit.

Comment: @DA01 nice one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clients are going to assume your page is a sample of your ability and also your style; if they think your style is absolutely unsuitable and they have no example of your work that IS of a suitable style they may well assume you're not right for the job.

However I don't think anyone is going to expect that your personal website should look exactly like their own final product should look like; if Disney wants you for a Disneyland kid-friendly, ad riddled page of fluffy bunnies, I don't think they're going to discount you just because your page doesn't include those elements.

Anyone competant that's scouting you out is going to understand that personal and corporate pages are different, and they're going to work with you to express what *they* want in the page because **they know you don't have the same objectives**.

If you don't feel your personal site shows off the kind of work you *could do* for a more corporate client, show off some examples of past work you have that you feel show off the style they want to see; branded navigation bars, well-integrated ads, whatever you think is important. If you don't have anything you can show, **create something you can show off in that style**.

Perhaps more important here is who evaluates your website; if someone totally ignorant of design is the one evaluating your design they may well make the decisions you fear here. Someone might see your site and think "Oh, that's all they can do", and yes, that's a lost client. **But is that a client you want to work with?**

Comment: Absolutely great answer. Cleared things in my mind.